# import a .sql file in my database on postgres on windows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, file, import

```
postgres-# \i C:\Users\Public\datafile.sql;
C:: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the forward slashes in path. as shown below

```
postgres=# \i C:/Users/Public/datafile.sql
```